# Parse a Json response array from server in javascript without loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am working on a webapp. I have a webpage that sends some data to the server via form tag. The server returns a json array. I want to know how to parse that json array without loading 
my page. The purpose is to keep my webpage as it is and load some values from json array to
some text fields below my form tag for further processing.

edit: I have tried some examples for reading from json array but how to prevent webpage realoading.

Comment: Just use Ajax instead of form submit.

Comment: @raghavv: Thanks for quick reply. I am not into ajax as of now. I want to use Javascript. Is it possible via javascript?

Comment: Ajax is available as html / dom functionality and done using javascript. There is no otherway to communicate.

Comment: @nhahtdh: There isn't much code. What i will paste is only a form and i receive a response that replaces my webpage which it shouldn't cause it's a phone app and i want to keep the page as it is.

Comment: @raghavv: Ok, if it's the only way to prevent from reloading then i guess i don't have much of an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use Ajax for this. Ajax calls are done using Javascript as per your requirement. If you are using library like JQuery it is quite simple to use.

Link to JQuery - Get: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

One of the ideas to save you from changing anything in your existing code is handle onsubmit of the form. Send your get/post on submit via ajax and cancel the submit of the form.

Comment: One of the ideas to save you from changing anything in your existing code is handle onsubmit of the form. Send your get/post on submit via ajax and cancel the submit of the form.

Comment: you mean i shouldn't submit via the form submit button but transfer the submit action to the the ajax calls to prevent reloading?

Comment: I was suggesting this to help you extra work. Basically you can cancel submit of any form in onsubmit event. My idea was while 'canceling submit', you also use the opportunity to send your ajax.

Comment: I have tried before what I said in my last comment by calling a function from a button in my form and then transferring it to an onsubmit event. Does creating an ajax call inside that function will help? I am getting what you are saying but can you provide a simple example of an ajax request.

Comment: Are you OK with JQuery? I can give sample in that case.

Comment: JQuery is cool. But right now i wouldn't use that. Just tell me one thing, i will have to manually create a url from form values if i have to make an ajax call? isn't it?

Comment: Yes. You will need to manually take all the value from the form like document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value